# Asynchronous counter retroaction problem VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have a problem with the following code, representing a generic asynchronous counter.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ASYNC_COUNTER is
    generic(NBIT:integer);
        port(
            CLK : in std_logic;
            COUNT : out std_logic_vector(NBIT-1 downto 0)
        );
end entity ASYNC_COUNTER;

architecture architectural of ASYNC_COUNTER is

    component FF is
    port(   INPUT, CLK: in std_logic;
            OUTPUT, NOUTPUT: out std_logic
    );
end component FF;

signal q: std_logic_vector(NBIT-1 downto 0);
signal retroaction: std_logic_vector(NBIT-1 downto 0);
signal first_in: std_logic := '0';

begin

ARCH: for i in 0 to NBIT-1 generate
    FIRST:if i=0 generate
        F1: FF
        port map(first_in, CLK, q(0), retroaction(0));
    end generate FIRST;
    first_in <= retroaction(0);
    OTHER:if i>0 generate
        F: FF
        port map(retroaction(i), q(i-1), q(i), retroaction(i));
    end generate OTHER;
end generate;

COUNT <= q;

end architecture architectural;
```

Of course the problem is the retroaction, but I don't know how to implement it in other ways.
Any suggestions?

Comment: And what is exactly your problem ?

Comment: There is no output. It is always set to U.

Comment: It seems to me like the output ports of your FF are uninitialized at simulation start, which leads to 'U' values propagating through the design.

Answer (score -1):

In this part of your code :

```
OTHER:if i>0 generate
    F: FF
    port map(retroaction(i), q(i-1), q(i), retroaction(i));
end generate OTHER;
```

You use `retroaction(i)` as input. This signal is never set with a known value. At startup, this signal is 'U' and at every clock cycles (`q(i-1)`cycles actually), it gets (not 'U') which is 'U'.

A solution is to initialize the retroaction signal to 0 in the declaration :

```
signal retroaction: std_logic_vector(NBIT-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

Comment: Even if this solution is working at least in simulation, It's strange to use a signal `q(i-1)` as a clock for your FF component. It could drive to strange behavior on FPGA. It's better to use one clock for all your FF, and to avoid using signals as clock inputs.

Comment: It does not work. But the sintax is correct, links as well. I really don't know

Comment: do you have any warnings ?

Comment: nothing! In addition I also tried to implement it with JK FFs, and the result is always the same!

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with testbench and FF block ?

Comment: OK solved. It was non initialization of a signal inside the flip flop, and so, when it had to toggle, it did not know how to. Now everything works fine.
Thank you so much for the ineterst anyway!!!